# edit text to permanent

Tags: java, android, text, edit

Good day everyone, I need help for this code. Lets say for example I have below Textview "Phone Owner" and EditText "Jerry Smith" (etJerrySmith is *editable ="true"*)

So I run app, I can change "Jerry Smith" into any name but when I close and run again, it returns to "Jerry Smith". Is there any way to change the "Jerry Smith" into perhaps "Meeseeks" and keep permanent ?

content_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">



<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText1"

    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   />

 <Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="saveName"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.lowellnc.edittopermanent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText editText1;

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    name = settings.getString("name", "USE_ANY_DEFAULT_NAME_HERE");
    editText1.setText(name);
}

public void saveName(View v) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String n = editText1.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(Name, n);
    editor.commit();
}
```

}

I edited it and here is my code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the newly entered value in shared preferences on click of a button or on close of the activity and when you open the application, inside onCreate() of this activity you should read the value from shared preferences and then set it back to edit text. In this way you will be able to set new values to above mentioned edittext.

If you use a button, code would be something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText1;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    name = sharedpreferences.getString("nameKey", "USE_ANY_DEFAULT_NAME_HERE");
    editText1.setText(name);
}

public void saveName(View v){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    String n = editText1.getText().toString();
    editor.putString(Name, n);
    editor.commit();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Hey, value you entered is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can create a button in your layout and set saveName() on the onClick of that button's xml. Then whenever you will press the button, it will grab the value of edittext and save it in shared preferences. Now whenever you will open the application again, the onCreate() will read values from shared preferences and set it on edittext.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: any chance i could get bits of code mate?  I ain't really good at this android or java

Comment: Sure! I was just writing small code for this. I do not have Android setup on my laptop. Forgive me if there are any mistakes in code, but code is likely to be same. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks  mate, I really appreciate it.

Comment: forgive the question but, what should I replace the "view" with ?

Comment: are you talking about xml layout which contains textview & edittext currently? if yes, then you need to add a button below the edittext and on onClick on that button you need to specify saveName() method. Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: when I run, the text in the EditText is "USE_ANY_DEFAULT_NAME_HERE" and i did edited it and clicked button then I closed and reopened and then went back to "USE_ANY_DEFAULT_NAME_HERE"

by the way, I edited my post above

Comment: Can you try this : name = settings.getString("nameKey", "USE_ANY_DEFAULT_NAME_HERE");

Comment: i close then after i open, the text is not changed

Comment: Ok No problem. Give me sometime, let me check it again. We will resolve your issue.

Comment: I made a mistake in copy paste, there are two objects of shared preferences, I think that is the issue. We need to put in one and read values back from the same. I will edit the code after running it

Comment: I have tested it and it is working. Could you please try modified code above. Sorry for the double objects issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you a lot sir, the codes worked. Although the "Hey, value you entered is saved" doesn't show up, but there is no need for you to waste more of your time for me, you already fulfilled my wish.

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to put .show() method. Edited. No time waste. Enjoy